# Wordpress Post ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to stop WordPress from allowing visitors to use post ID to access some specific pages.

For example: http://example.com/?p=2 will get them on http://example.com/some-page/, however if they change the number on http://example.com/?p=3 they will get http://example.com/another-page/.

But I would like to stop that and block any URLs with post ID. So if they use http://example.com/?p=3 they will get nothing, no page, only a 404 error. Any idea how to block this?

Comment: A hack would be to modify a common include file to check for $_GET['p'] and redirect to a nonextant URL.  Perhaps a better solution would be to modify .htaccess (I'm assuming you are using Apache) to forbid this parameter.

Comment: Good idea, I will try to find on internet how to do that and I will try it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question but if it is about posts, you could change your permalinks in `settings -> permalinks` and use post name, and then the article's URL should change to its title rather than it's ID. Subsequently if someone tries to access something like http://example.com/?p=3 they'd be redirected to the main page (homepage). Plus, it is more SEO friendly to have URLs with titles than just ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not enough just to change permalinks, WordPress will redirect links like ?p= to the appropriate URLs anyway.

By steps:

1. In Settings > Permalinks change it to any option except default.
2. Add this code at the beginning of your header.php file.

   ```
   if( !empty( $_GET['p'] ) ){
       wp_redirect( site_url() ); // redirect to the homepage
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but its no working :( when I go on www.example.com/?p=6719 I am redirected on the page with that ID (6719) but I would like to prevent that and redirect people on homepage or somewhere else, but not give them possibility to go to /?p=6719 and just change the number for something different.